# Aluffi Alg. Chapter 0 Exercise 7.1.3

Tags: field-theory

[image]

The first part of this exercise seems straightforward to me, but I'm a bit confused about the second part. In the case $\alpha$ is transcendental we know that $k(\alpha)$ is actually isomorphic to $k(t)$ so it must be referring to the case where $\alpha$ is algebraic. But in that case I'm not sure how to show that there might not be an onto homomorphism?

Comment: here's a hint: what would the kernel of this morphism be?

Comment: There is ambiguity in what "this" is, in "why does this not give (in general) an onto homomorphism," as the preceding material does not expressly define any map (or candidate map) from $k(t)$ to $k(\alpha)$. One is left to wonder whether the author asks why there is not (in general) an onto homomorphism from $k(t)$ to $k(\alpha)$ *having the property that $t$ is mapped to $\alpha$*, as suggested by his discussion of what elements of $k(\alpha)$ "may be written as," or why there is not (in general) an onto homomorphism from $k(t)$ to $k(\alpha)$, period. I expect he means the first question.

Comment: I expect the same, or more precisely: Aluffi means to ask why the onto homomorphism he seemingly defines, $k(t)\to k(\alpha),\;f\mapsto f(\alpha)$, is (in general) actually not well-defined. And the answer holds in one sentence: because $p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$ is undefined when $q(\alpha)=0$. No need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Brian Shin has given the answer, but let me write out some more details.

So the basic reason is that a field homomorphism is either 0 or injective, by the consideration of its kernel as an ideal in the domain field.

In the case at hand, since $k(t)\to k(\alpha)$ can't be injective when $\alpha$ is algebraic by dimension reasons, the homomorphism must be 0.

Therefore, there is no such a thing as a "quotient field", although quotient groups and quotient rings are so important.

Incidentally, if $f\in k[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then
$$
k[x]/(f)\overset\cong\to k(\alpha); \ [g(x)]\to g(\alpha).
$$
So a quotient ring just happens to be a field, since $f$ is irreducible.

Also note that this natural homomorphism $k[x]\to k(\alpha)$ can't be extended to $k(x)$, because the natural candidate $g(x)/h(x)\to g(\alpha)/h(\alpha)$ is not defined when $h(\alpha)=0$, which happens in particular when $f|h$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I guess part of what threw me off was the "onto" bit. If you're saying the only possible morphism is the zero one, why didn't he say "there is no nonzero homomorphism"? Like if he's written "there is no injective map" then it'd of been easy.

Comment: I think the author is trying to stress the surprising bit that although all elements in $k(\alpha)$ are rational functions of $\alpha$, there is no homomorphism from the field $k(t)$ of rational functions to it though, when $\alpha$ is algebraic. The reason again is that the map send $t$ to $\alpha$ is not defined when the denominator has value 0 at $\alpha$. (I had fun thinking about this question, and I have to admit that it did surprise me.)